# C# Making a new instance of a class with or without "var"

Tags: c#, instance, var

Lets say I have a class called `Person`, that Id like to make a new instance of. From my testing, both of theese examples work.

```
var Mike = new Person();
```

seems to do the same thing as

```
Person Mike = new Person();
```

My question is, what is the difference, and which one is "generally better".

Comment: Yes, it is the same and it is basically a matter of taste. The only place where you actually need `var` is when constructing a variable of an anonymous type.

Comment: Oh, so it's just all about the code style, and doesn't change the functionality of the code at all?

Comment: Yes, if your model name is too long, you can use "var".